# What kind of temperature sensor is this?

Tags: resistors, temperature

What kind of temperature sensor is this? What would be the best method for getting a reading from it?

[image: RTD or Thermistor?]

Comment: Related.  [Similar question about identifying a temperature sensor.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/107558/7036)

Comment: Are you sure it's a temperature sensor?  can you supply a little more detail about where it came from, etc.?

Comment: It came out of this: http://www.walmart.com/ip/Mainstays-Digital-Meat-Thermometer-00641W/14913168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is a [Thermocouple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple). You can read it with a [thermocouple amplifier like this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/269). Here is a [tutorial on how to read from the device](https://learn.adafruit.com/thermocouple/wiring-the-thermocouple).

**EDIT:**
Upon further review of the image it could be a [Thermistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) in which case you would just read the voltage drop across it like any other resistor.

Comment: Would it be an RTD or traditional Thermistor?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the image but I would say it is a traditional Thermistor.